# WSO2 AM unable to create API after adding roles with soap call

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using a soap call to create the roles and users correctly. I can view then just fine in the webpage and all the check boxes that need to be selected are, base on the documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Adding+User+Roles)

But I am not able to create the API with after that. I get this error:
User apicreator does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

However, if I go to the role in the webpage and view the permissions, then click update without changing anything it then works.

**Soap curl command to create the role:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -k 
--header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" 
--header "SOAPAction:urn:addRole" -d @soaprole.xml 
--url https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint
```

**soaprole.xml:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://dao.service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ser:addRole>
    <ser:roleName>creator</ser:roleName>
    <ser:permissions>
      <xsd:action>ui.execute</xsd:action>
      <xsd:resourceId>/permission/admin/Manage/API</xsd:resourceId>
    </ser:permissions>
    <ser:permissions>
      <xsd:action>ui.execute</xsd:action>
      <xsd:resourceId>/permission/admin/login</xsd:resourceId>
    </ser:permissions>
    <ser:permissions>
      <xsd:action>ui.execute</xsd:action>
      <xsd:resourceId>/permission/admin/configure/governance</xsd:resourceId>
    </ser:permissions>
    <ser:permissions>
      <xsd:action>ui.execute</xsd:action>
      <xsd:resourceId>/permission/admin/Manage/resources/govern/api</xsd:resourceId>
    </ser:permissions>
    <ser:permissions>
      <xsd:action>ui.execute</xsd:action>
      <xsd:resourceId>/permission/admin/Manage/resources/govern</xsd:resourceId>
    </ser:permissions>
  </ser:addRole>
```

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? This is a major blocker for me right now.

Comment: Anyone? This has completely stopped my work.